# what is the meaning of the expression " x * Math.cos(angle) - y * Math.sin(angle)"?

Tags: javascript, expression, trigonometry

The above expression was taken from the below method.
I know that to rotate a point around the center we have to

1. Move the point to the origin
2. Make the rotation and
3. Move the point back

But the pieces I don't get my head around are:

```
r[0] = x * Math.cos(angle) - y * Math.sin(angle);
                           ^
                           |
                          why we use the minus sign here?

r[1] = x * Math.sin(angle) + y * Math.cos(angle);
                           ^
                           |
                            And why here we use plus sign instead of minus?



Vec2.prototype.rotate = function (center, angle) {
//rotate in counterclockwise
var r = [];
var x = this.x - center.x;
var y = this.y - center.y;
r[0] = x * Math.cos(angle) - y * Math.sin(angle);
r[1] = x * Math.sin(angle) + y * Math.cos(angle);
r[0] += center.x;
r[1] += center.y;
return new Vec2(r[0], r[1]);
};
```

---

The book was to be great but it doesn't explain most of the code it simply spits out.

Comment: which book are you reading?

Comment: They are components of the [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix).

Comment: The part I'm interested in is : x′=xcosθ−ysinθ

Comment: The book is "Building a 2d game physics Engine"

Comment: @EllsonMendes: the comment from Niet has a link that should explain it.  In essence, a counterclockwise rotation of `(x, y)` through angle `θ` can be done by that  transformation of `x` and `y` into `x'` and `y'` once you've normalized to the center of `(0, 0)`.

Comment: Yes I know they are components but I'd like someone to explain this part:
x * Math.cos(angle) - y * Math.sin(angle)
why we get the cosine of the angle *x position MINUS sine of the angle * y position, plz

Answer (score 0):

I got it! Just saw a video of Dr Peyam on transformation matrix.

To get x' and y'  we multiply the transformation matrix by the current coordinate (x,y)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NK4i6.png)